# How to obtain eigenvectors in AceGen

Tags: linear-algebra, acegen

I'm trying to obtain eigenvectors of a 3D plastic stretch tensor **$C_p$**. There is no `SMSEigenvectors` function, so I tried with `Eigenvectors[Cp]`, but internal error occurs:

> Internal error: SMSStrictFunction
>
> Subroutine: SKR Description: {{1.00000,Null^3.0}}

I was guessing it is because **$C_p$** is internal variable of the problem and is defined by some other variables, so I also tried with numerical values: `Eigenvectors[N[Cp]]`. Error is gone, however calculated result is wrong. I took a closer look at it and noticed that `N[Cp]` does not evaluate **$C_P$** correctly, therefore calculated eigenvectors are wrong.

**Questions:**

1. Why function `N[]` gives wrong numerical values?
2. Is there another way to calculate eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 2.:

Newer version of AceGen includes function `SMSEigensystem`, which calculates eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors. Updating AceGen package to latest release is the solution.